# Invariance of d'Alembertian for Lorentz boost in arbitrary directions

Tags: special-relativity, differentiation

I am having trouble in showing the invariance of the d'Alembertian operator subject to Lorentz boost along arbitrary directions. Generally, this proof in textbook (that I've seen) is done either by using index notation or assuming the boost to be along a particular axis (say, $x$ or $z$). That's why I am unable to resolve this issue simply by referring to the books. Below I show my attempt in details

Unprimed and primed coordinates

$$x = ({\color{gray} c}t,\boldsymbol{x});~~x' = ({\color{gray} c}t',\boldsymbol{x'}).$$

The Lorentz boost matrix between them $x' = \Lambda \cdot x$, where

\begin{align}
    \Lambda = \begin{pmatrix}
        \gamma & -\gamma\frac{\boldsymbol{v}^{\mathsf{T}}}{\color{gray}c} \\
        -\gamma\frac{\boldsymbol{v}}{\color{gray} c} & \mathbb{I}_{3} + \left(\gamma - 1 \right)\frac{\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{v}^{\mathsf{T}}}{\boldsymbol{v\cdot v}}
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

The transformation for the partial derivatives

\begin{align}
    \boldsymbol{\nabla_{x'}}&=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}{\partial \boldsymbol{x'}}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla_{x}}+\frac{\partial t}{\partial \boldsymbol{x'}}\partial_t\nonumber\\
    &=\boldsymbol{\nabla_{x}} + \frac{\left(\gamma-1\right)\boldsymbol{v}}{\boldsymbol{v\cdot v}}\left(\boldsymbol{v\cdot \nabla_{x}}\right) - \gamma \frac{\boldsymbol{v}}{{\color{gray}{c^2}}}\partial_{t}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \partial_{t'}&=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}{\partial t'}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla_{x}}+\frac{\partial t}{\partial t'}\partial_t\nonumber\\
    &=\gamma\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla_{x}} + \gamma \partial_{t}.
\end{align}

Then the corresponding second derivatives read

\begin{align}
    \boldsymbol{\nabla_{x'}\cdot\nabla_{x'}}
    =&\boldsymbol{\nabla_{x}\cdot\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}} + \frac{\gamma^2}{\color{gray}{c^2}}\left(\boldsymbol{v\cdot\nabla_{x}}\right)^2\nonumber\\
    & - 2 \frac{\gamma^2}{\color{gray}{c^2}} \left(\boldsymbol{v\cdot\nabla_{x}}\right)\partial_{t} +\gamma^2 \frac{\boldsymbol{v}^2}{\color{gray}{c^4}}  \partial^2_{t}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \partial^2_{t'} & = \gamma^2\partial^2_{t} + \gamma^2 \left(\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla_{x}}\right)^2 + 2 \gamma^2  \left(\boldsymbol{v\cdot\nabla_{x}}\right)\partial_{t}, 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \boldsymbol{\nabla_{x'}\cdot\nabla_{x'}} - \frac{1}{{\color{gray}c^2}} \partial^2_{t'}
    = & \boldsymbol{\nabla_{x}\cdot\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}} + \frac{\gamma^2}{\color{gray}{c^2}}\left(\boldsymbol{v\cdot\nabla_{x}}\right)^2 - 2 \frac{\gamma^2}{\color{gray}{c^2}} \left(\boldsymbol{v\cdot\nabla_{x}}\right)\partial_{t} +\gamma^2 \frac{\boldsymbol{v}^2}{\color{gray}{c^4}}  \partial^2_{t} \nonumber\\
& -\frac{\gamma^2}{\color{gray}{c^2}}\partial^2_{t} - \frac{\gamma^2}{\color{gray}{c^2}} \left(\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla_{x}}\right)^2 - 2 \frac{\gamma^2}{\color{gray}{c^2}}  \left(\boldsymbol{v\cdot\nabla_{x}}\right)\partial_{t} \nonumber \\
& = \boldsymbol{\nabla_{x}\cdot\nabla_{x}} - \frac{1}{{\color{gray}c^2}} \partial^2_{t} {\color{red}{ - 4 \frac{\gamma^2}{\color{gray}{c^2}}  \left(\boldsymbol{v\cdot\nabla_{x}}\right)\partial_{t}}}.
\end{align}

I know that I'm missing something, but do not know what. Kindly help me figuring this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to have a thorough look at this, but maybe this could be the problem. In your first equation with $\nabla_{\mathbf x'}$ you calculate $\frac{\partial t}{\partial\mathbf x'}$. To evaluate this you have calculated $x=\Lambda^{-1}x'$ and taking derivatives. To calculate the inverse of $\Lambda$ you should replace every occurence of $\mathbf v/c$ with $-\mathbf v/c$. This leaves your matrix with $+\gamma$ everywhere. Therefore, your expression for $\frac{\partial t}{\partial\mathbf x'}$ should be positive but the last term is negative.